# Character vector as an argument to spread_draws from Tidybayes

Tags: r, stan

How can I pass a character to spread_draws. Let's say I have a fit from Stan, and I want to do the following:

```
parameters <- c("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
spread_draws(stan_fit, parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the character vector `parameters` to a list of symbols with `syms(parameters)` and insert them with `!!!`.

```
spread_draws(stan_fit, !!!syms(parameters))
```

https://github.com/mjskay/tidybayes/issues/38#issuecomment-546129065